# Community Connector needs to be re-authorized every couple of days

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

The issue is following:
I created a  community connector that is used by couple of people in my company. The roles of users are the following:

1. Me - the script owner and editor
2. Person 1 - Responsible for creating Data Studio reports (viewer access to my script)
3. Person 2 - recipient of the reports (no direct access to the script)

**Script Setup:**

Script is not public. The owner and editor is me. The viewer is Person 1. Google Cloud project is in "Publishing Status = TESTING" with my and Person 1's email addresses added as Test Users.
Authentication type of the connector is `AuthType.USER_PASS`

**The  Issue**

Every couple of days reports created by Person 1 become inaccessible to everybody they are shared with, due to the fact that Data Source is no longer authorized. What Person 1 needs to do everytime is to go back to the Authorization view and authorize connector again:

[image]

What's important is that after the re-autorization there is no need to re-enter login and password so they are obviously persisted in  `PropertiesService`. The issue seems to affect only the initial script authorization step. Also it does not affect reports that I own (being an owner of the script). Only reports owned and created by Person 1 are affected.
Any ideas what might be causing this?

P.S. I figured that perhaps making Person 1 editor of the script instead of viewer might fix the issue, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that switching to publishing status "in production" fixed the problem. It's been around 2 weeks since I've done so and connector remains authorized.
I believe it should be clearly stated in docs or inside the panel that when project is in "testing" mode OAuth authoruization expires after couple of days. Otherwise it is confusing.